# How to load JavaScript in WordPress

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, scripting

I need to know if this is the correct way to load JavaScript using functions.php

```
function wd_load_script() {
    wp_deregister_script( 'jquery' );
    wp_register_script( 'jquery', 'http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js', false, '1.10.2', true);
    wp_register_script('cufon-yui', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/cufin-yui.js', 'jquery');
    wp_register_script('cufon-aller', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/cufon-aller.js', 'jquery');
    wp_register_script('script', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/script.js', 'jquery');
    wp_register_script('coin-slider.min', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/coin-slider.min.js', 'jquery');

    wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery' );
    wp_enqueue_script( 'cufon-yui' );
    wp_enqueue_script( 'cufon-aller' );
    wp_enqueue_script( 'script' );
    wp_enqueue_script( 'coin-slider.min' );

}    
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'wd_load_script');
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes that code is the correct way to load JavaScript in WP although the third parameter of `wp_register_script` should be an array. `array( 'jquery' )` instead of `'jquery'`.

For example change:

```
wp_register_script('cufon-yui', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/cufin-yui.js', 'jquery');
```

To:

```
wp_register_script('cufon-yui', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/cufin-yui.js', array( 'jquery' ) );
```

Comment: thanks, but really meaning the parameter array ('jquery')? it for?

Comment: If I understand that question correctly you're asking why `array('jquery')` is used. It's to tell WordPress to only load the file after jQuery has been loaded as it requires jQuery to function. Take a look here for more info: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_register_script